# WCF handle ungraceful disconnects in serviceHost

Tags: wcf, disconnect, servicehost

Is there a way to handle disconnects from a client that hasn't Closed the connection properly?
I set up a test program that opened alot of connections to my wcf ServiceHost. I didn't close those connections properly.

After awhile the Server stopped receiving new connections, most likely due to MaxConcurrentSessions was reached? This wasn't resolved until i restarted the service, or after a long timeout?. Very nice denial of Service...

So how can i handle this on the server side?
Is it possible to detect when a client has disconnected instead of closed the connection?
Is it possible to disconnect the client automatically after the OperationContract has returned?

I need to free up the disconnected sessions so that i can start receiving new connections.

Comment: Are you sure the ServiceHost limits kicked in, not the OS limits? If those connections are TCP/IP the OS networkstack might need tuning as well.

Comment: Yes, im sure it was the ServiceHost limit that kicked in. I set it to 10 to test. If i set it higher the problem wont appear for a much longer time.